# Uso un ordenador compartido ¿Como puedo manterner segura mi cuenta de git?

Tags: git, github

Estoy haciendo un curso en un ordenador compartido y estoy guardando mi trabajo en github.

Pero claro... el repositorio esta ligado a la cuenta de github y podrían hacer pushes malintencionados en el repositorio.

¿Como haría para desvincular las credenciales de git del ordenador y de mi proyecto de mi cuenta cada vez que acabo la clase?

Una especie de logout de git.

Comment: al hacer git push te pide clave, salvo que lo tengas con llaves

Comment: Pues lo debo tener con llaves ¿Se llaman asi?  no encuentro info al respecto(he hecho una busqueda muy somera) ¿como las quito?

Comment: Estan en un archivo de configuracion.. fijate info sobre eso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes desinstalar el `"Credential manager"`de Git. Para ello,

Asumiendo que estás en `windows`:

navega desde la terminal a: `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core` (o su equivalente para `x86`) y coloca:

> **git credential-manager uninstall --force**

Si estás en `linux`, intentar con:

> **git config --global --unset credential.helper**

De esta forma, debería pedirte credenciales para cualquier comando que apunte al servidor remoto.

*Tomado de: [How do I disable Git Credential Manager for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182847/how-do-i-disable-git-credential-manager-for-windows)*